# Synchronous callout before record creation for validation at external site

Tags: apex, callout

My requirement is to validate leads at external site before creating lead records in Salesforce.If the validation is successful, it must create a lead record else,errors must be thrown (In real time)
What should be an approach?
Of course we can't use asynchronous ways (Future method/Batch Apex etc)
Also, leads can be created either through Salesforce UI or can be loaded using import wizard/ data loader.

Comment: Your question as written is too broad. Are you expecting to have a solution that works for single record UI that will also be a solution for multi-record import? Tell us what you've considered, tried, ruled-out, etc or show us the code you've written & where you're stuck to narrow the scope of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too broad.

To validate lead data quality recommended to use Validation Rules.

And, to validate duplicate lead records, use Duplicate Management in Salesforce.

Both of them will support for Single record insert as well as bulk import either from UI or import wizard/dataloader.